# Get words corresponding to a match from SpanNearQuery in Lucene

Tags: lucene, html, text-analysis

I would need to retrieve the words in my text that correspond to a match of Spans returned by SpanNearQuery.getSpans(). For instance, if my text is [a b c d e f] and I use SpanNearQueries with queries 'b' and 'e' (and sufficient slop), then I get a match 'b c d e' in my text. Now, how can I most efficiently retrieve the words as they appear in the match, that is, the sequence of words 'b c d e' itself?

Here is an example code of what I would need:

```
SpanNearQuery allNear = new SpanNearQuery(spansTermQueries, numWordsInBetween, true);
Spans allSpans = allNear.getSpans(reader);
```

Now I would like to iterate over all the matches in allSpans, and for each match retrieve the exact words between the queries 9 the text that correspond to that match.

One indirect way is to get the end and start position of that match, read through the text document using a file reader, and find the string of text between position 'end' and 'start'. But that does not seem a very efficient way. It seems that this information should already be stored in the Lucene Index.

Would anyone know of a more direct way of retrieving the words between the queries in a match?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is [highlighting](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/package-summary.html). You can either use the plain highlighter or [fast vector highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/contrib-fast-vector-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/vectorhighlight/FastVectorHighlighter.html) if you store term vectors.